# Creating depth generator failed. Fedora, Kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, fedora, openni-launch, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying run Kinect with OpenNI drivers on Fedora 15 and ROS Diamondback.
So, using tutorial ( [this one](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera#openni_camera.2BAC8-diamondback.OpenNI_Demo) ), I compile drivers without errors:

```
rosmake openni_camera
```

Next, I export this parameters:

```
ROS_HOSTNAME="localhost"
ROS_MASTER_URI="http://localhost:11311"
```

But, when I try to launch Kinect, I got next messages:

```
[ WARN] [1315135571.124613017]: The input topic '/camera/rgb/image_mono' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1315135571.125195980]: The input topic '/camera/rgb/camera_info' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1315135572.505867242]: The input topic '/camera/depth_registered/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1315135572.687120215]: The input topic '/camera/rgb/image_color' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1315135572.687495681]: The input topic '/camera/rgb/camera_info' is not yet advertised

[ INFO] [1315135574.007773568]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1315135574.008287528]: 1. device on bus 002:15 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00365921222043A'
[ INFO] [1315135574.010913481]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1315135574.071555280]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::OpenNIDevice(xn::Context&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&) @ /home/crady/openni_kinect/openni_kinect/openni_camera/src/openni_device.cpp @ 61 : creating depth generator failed. Reason: The network connection has been closed!
```

During this, process XnSensorServer is active.
Thanks for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9912/creating-depth-generator-failed.-fedora,-kinect./) by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 546 on 2011-09-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2011-10-27**:
Same problem with Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric), using ros-electric from natty (11.04), since it's not available in oneiric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think, that found problem. On fedora, when you compile driver openni_kinect, there some missing packages:

```
Failed to find rosdep openni-dev for package openni_camera on OS:fedora version:15
Failed to find rosdep libusb1.0 for package openni_camera on OS:fedora version:15
Failed to find rosdep ps-engine for package openni_camera on OS:fedora version:15
WARNING: Rosdeps [u'openni-dev', u'libusb1.0', u'ps-engine'] could not be resolved
```

---

Originally posted by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) with karma: 546 on 2011-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0